# Keyboard shortcut to switch between Google accounts?

Tags: google-account

I use multiple accounts with various Google web apps, including Gmail, Calendar, Docs/Drive, and Voice. Is there any way to get a keyboard shortcut to switch among accounts?

Comment: Five tabs followed by Enter seems to work (assuming your focus isn't elsewhere) but not a specific keyboard shortcut I've found (yet).

Comment: You might be able to hack something together yourself using bookmark shortcuts and specially formatted URLs. http://lifehacker.com/5733636/switch-between-multiple-gmail-accounts-with-a-url-hack

Answer (score 2):

I use [different Google Chrome profiles](https://superuser.com/questions/361743/how-do-i-make-two-different-google-chrome-profiles). Each Google Chrome profile is logged to a different account. I can then just use the [keyboard shortcut to switch between the different Google Chrome profiles](https://superuser.com/questions/438039/how-to-quickly-change-user-profile-in-google-chrome).

Comment: this answer would be better if you explain creating google profiles and the shortcut to switch between them